How to do runtime changes to the filter level for logs using tracing library in Rust
I have a Rust application I am instrumenting, and I would like to be able to set the log filtering level dynamically for a given span tree. Note that I don't want to change the log level for the whole application by doing something like reloading the filter layer with a new level - I want to set the filter level for a specific execution of a given code path.
I was able to implement this behavior by adding a meta-field always-log to the parent span, propagating that field to child spans through it's extensions and then filtering conditionally on the presence of either the field or the extension:

use tracing::span::Attributes;
use tracing::{span, Level, Subscriber};
use tracing_core::{Interest, Metadata};
use tracing_subscriber::fmt;
use tracing_subscriber::layer::{Context, Layer, SubscriberExt};
use tracing_subscriber::registry::LookupSpan;

struct PropagateExtensionLayer;

struct AlwaysLog;

impl<S> Layer<S> for PropagateExtensionLayer
where
    S: Subscriber + for<'lookup> LookupSpan<'lookup>,
{
    fn on_new_span(
        &self,
        _attrs: &Attributes<'_>,
        id: &tracing_core::span::Id,
        ctx: Context<'_, S>,
    ) {
        let span = ctx.span(id).unwrap();
        let should_propagate_field = span
            .fields()
            .iter()
            .any(|field| field.name() == "always_log")
            || span.parent().map_or(false, |parent| {
                parent.extensions().get::<AlwaysLog>().is_some()
            });

        if should_propagate_field {
            span.extensions_mut().insert(AlwaysLog);
        }
    }

    fn register_callsite(&self, metadata: &'static Metadata<'static>) -> Interest {
        if metadata
            .fields()
            .iter()
            .any(|field| field.name() == "always_log")
        {
            Interest::always()
        } else {
            Interest::sometimes()
        }
    }
}

pub struct FilterLayer;

impl<S> Layer<S> for FilterLayer
where
    S: tracing::Subscriber + for<'lookup> LookupSpan<'lookup>,
{
    fn enabled(&self, metadata: &tracing::Metadata<'_>, ctx: Context<'_, S>) -> bool {
        let always_log = metadata
            .fields()
            .iter()
            .any(|field| field.name() == "always_log")
            || ctx
                .lookup_current()
                .map_or(false, |span| span.extensions().get::<AlwaysLog>().is_some());
        always_log || metadata.level() <= &Level::ERROR
    }
}

fn main() {
    let subscriber = tracing_subscriber::registry()
        .with(FilterLayer)
        .with(PropagateExtensionLayer)
        .with(fmt::Layer::default());

    tracing::subscriber::set_global_default(subscriber).expect("Failed to set subscriber");

    let parent_span = span!(Level::INFO, "parent", always_log = true, key1 = "value1");
    parent_span.in_scope(|| {
        let child_span = span!(Level::INFO, "child", key2 = "value2");
        child_span.in_scope(|| {
            tracing::info!("This should be logged and parent spans activated");
        });
    });

    let parent_span = span!(Level::INFO, "parent", key1 = "value1");
    parent_span.in_scope(|| {
        let child_span = span!(Level::INFO, "child", key2 = "value2");
        child_span.in_scope(|| {
            tracing::info!("This should not be logged");
            tracing::error!("This should also be logged but parent spans deactivated");
        });
    });
}

However, I am not sure this is the best way of doing this. Although it is simple to drop this meta-field later, I would rather add the extension directly to the first span, but I can't figure out how or if it is at all possible, since on_new_span is only called for spans the subscriber has an interest in, and that comes from register_callsite which only sees the span metadata.
I am also unsure if this is the best approach for doing this, as I suspect with all the stuff in the tracing ecosystem, there might be a better way. However, given that the real application is reasonably complex with the same call moving around many threads, I would like to avoid messing too much with creating new subscribers with new filters (unless, of course, there is a sensible way to do that and keep track of them for an operation that jumps all over)
So my questions are:

Is there a way to create a span directly with an extension and also force it to be enabled, conditionally?
Is there a simpler, better or more canonical way to achieve this conditional filtering behavior, either improving this solution or with a different approach?
Why is the child span in the first example being enabled? In my understanding, it shouldn't be (although I'm glad it is) - no subscribers are declaring an interest in it, so it wouldn't make it to on_new_span, causing it to be rejected by the filter layer, disabling it like the two spans in the second example.


You can use an EnvFilter to enable the traces for spans that contain a given field with a filter like [{always_log=true}]

Yes but then I would have to add this field to every span in the call tree, which would require me to write it out because I can't (I believe) propagate the parent fields inside the on_new_span function like I did with the extensions, and then to decide if I want to use the field or not for each span I would have to drag the control variable through the entire tree, which I also don't want to do.
Or is there a way to write a directive such that if the span or any parent have the field it is enabled?

To make it more clear, I don't want to conditionally enable a specific span - I want t, be able to, at runtime, say "this time, don't filter any spans or logs that are created inside this span" without having to add an if always_log { event_with_field!(...) } else { event!(...) } everywhere or changing the filter behavior for other invocations of that path

That's what EnvFilter with [{always_log}] does: playground (note: this won't run on the playground because tracing is missing)

Wow, I tried something similar at first but it did not work, but this really does what I want, thank you very much! Do you want to add this as an answer so I can accept it?
